# Oracle PL/SQL Release 12.2.0.1.0 vs 12.1.0.2.0 - execute immediate with parameters

Tags: oracle, plsql, execute-immediate

```
DECLARE
  max_id INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT MAX(ID) + 1 INTO max_id FROM MY_TABLE;

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE SEQUENCE  MY_TABLE_ID  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 99999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH ' || max_id || ' CACHE 100 NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOPARTITION';

END;
```

Above gives me `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended` when executed on

```
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 12.2.0.1.0 - Production
```

and works without errors on

```
   Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
```

After I change the execute statement to the below, it works on both versions without any errors.

```
 CREATE SEQUENCE  MY_TABLE_ID  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 99999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH ' || max_id || '''
```

Is this a known issue?

Comment: It is unclear where it works, and where it does not as you posted 12.2.0.1.0 twice (both in "doesn't work" and "works").

Comment: @Littlefoot Updated the question

Comment: You edited the message, but 12.2.0.1.0 still stands in both statements. Have a closer look.

Comment: @Littlefoot Really sorry about it. Corrected now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not a `NOPARTITION` option according to either the [12cR1](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_6017.htm) or [12cR2](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/CREATE-SEQUENCE.html) documentation.

The statment does work in 12cR1 but appears to be silently ignored, since it doesn't appear to do anything - though it may be under the hood, as @XING's demo suggests. And it errors are expected in 12cR2 and 11gR2.

So this *seems* to be an undocumented (according to a MoS search) bug in 12cR1, in that it doesn't cause an error when an invalid option is included. Except... there are a few hits in MoS that refer to it indirectly as being valid, e.g. bug 23210794 where specifying the option is shown as a workaround; conversely doc ID 2253744.1 mentions

> `PARTITION`/`NOPARTITION` keyword, which is not a 12.1 feature, was used during the sequence creation

Interestingly the `all_sequences` view gained a `partition_count` column in [12cR1](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-5867804F-1339-4CB6-9A56-6B6DCECB61BB.htm), but then lost it again in [12cR2](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/refrn/ALL_SEQUENCES.html). (Purely speculation, but perhaps this is related to the internal implementation of auto-increment columns for partitioned tables, and wan't really meant to be exposed for other sequences.)

For more information you would need to raise a service request with Oracle.

But the fix to your problem is to remove the `NOPARTITION` keyword from your statement.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned by @Alex, creating a sequence with Partition clause is undocumented feature like `WMCONCAT`. See below explaination:

```
sql> create sequence s1;

Sequence created.

sql> select s1.nextval from dual;

     NEXTVAL
     ---------
     1

sql> select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('SEQUENCE','S1') from dual;

DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('SEQUENCE','S1')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 CREATE SEQUENCE  "SCOTT"."S1"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 99999999999999999999999999
99 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 21 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOPARTITION
```

You can see here that internally oracle saves the sequence definition in some `partition` and hence it shows in `DDL`.

Create another sequence

```
sql> create sequence s2 partition;

  Sequence created.

sql> select s2.nextval from dual;

     NEXTVAL
---------------
      4103920000000000000000000000000001

sql> select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('SEQUENCE','S2') from dual;

DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('SEQUENCE','S2')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

 CREATE SEQUENCE  "SCOTT"."S2"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 99999999999999999999999999
99 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 21 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE  PARTITION 100000000
```

You see now this time Oracle created sequence in some partiton and hence showed that in DDL definiton.

Some features oracle had reserved for its own internal usage which is hence kept undocumented.

In your case if you remove that part other part will work fine. See below:

```
DECLARE
  max_id INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT MAX(ID) + 1 INTO max_id FROM MY_TABLE;

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE SEQUENCE  MY_TABLE_ID  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 99999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH '|| max_id||'  CACHE 100 NOORDER  NOCYCLE  ' ;
END;
```