# Oracle Sequence generator returns a negative value , when the sequence number is stored in Java variable

Tags: java, oracle, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have a database column named Record ID . This is a primary key and its value is generated using an oracle sequence which has the below properties
Sequence Details
Min Value : 1
max Value : 9999999999999999999999999999
increment by : 10

In my Java application , I insert records into the table after applying some business logic . The value for the field Record ID , is got from a sequence generator

Before inserting a record , in Java code I first set its ID in a Java Long Variable with below code ( got from a sequence generator )

```
public static final String recordSequenceSQL= "SELECT RECORD_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL"

Long recordID = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(SELECT_EVENT_LOG_SEQUENCE_SQL, Long.class);

recordDao.save(recordID , record_name ,age);
```

The recordID value shows as  -8742538778 ( after I receive this value from sequence generator) , which has a minus sign in front of it .

I need to make sure that there is no negative values received . I'm not sure of the root cause and also need a solution to the same

Comment: If it increments by 10, how come that the last sequence digit is 8? Anyway: if sequence number *is* correct, apply the ABS function to the value (or multiply it by -1) and you'll get a positive number. That's pretty much all I can say about it, regarding I don't know Java.

Comment: If this sequence is supposed to provide the PK for the table, then don't have your app try to capture and use it.  Just create a trigger on the table to pull the sequence and provide it.  Or if your db is version is 12c or greater, define the PK as an identity column and let Uncle Oracle take care of it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To trouble shoot try the following steps

**Check the Sequence**

Connect with your application user and run the following query:

```
select SEQUENCE_OWNER, SEQUENCE_NAME, MIN_VALUE, MAX_VALUE, INCREMENT_BY, CACHE_SIZE, LAST_NUMBER
from all_sequences 
where SEQUENCE_NAME = 'RECORD_ID_SEQ';

SEQUENCE_OWNER                 SEQUENCE_NAME                   MIN_VALUE  MAX_VALUE                   INCREMENT_BY CACHE_SIZE LAST_NUMBER
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ---------- ---------------------------- ------------ ---------- -----------
<owner>                        RECORD_ID_SEQ                           1 9999999999999999999999999999           10         20     1202020
```

The important value is in the column `LAST_NUMBER` which is *approximately* the value you get by calling the `NEXTVAL`.

You will **not see** a *negative* number (if so contanct Oracle support immediately).

What you should see is a modest number as in may example.

One potential problem is if you see a number that is higher than `9223372036854775807` which is the max value for `Long`, but is valid number below the *sequence* `MAX_VALUE`.

But even in this case you will not get a negative number from your `JdbcTemplate` query - instead you will get an `Numeric Overflow` exception

```
Caught: org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: 
StatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [SELECT RECORD_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL]; 
SQLstate [99999];
error code [17026]; 
Numeric Overflow; 
nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Numeric Overflow
```

**Summary**

The problem with the negative value  is most probably in the `SELECT_EVENT_LOG_SEQUENCE_SQL`query (which you did not show).

**Further Suggestions**

While using the `Long` type for the `ID` column adjust the MAX_VALUE of the sequence to the max value of `LONG` see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58574009/4808122) for further discussion

If you expect heavy used sequence, do not use `INCREMENT_BY` 10, but stay on `1`

Comment: To the suggestion you made "The problem with the negative value is most probably in the SELECT_EVENT_LOG_SEQUENCE_SQLquery" . This helped . Just before the update query the SQL types defined was TYPES.INTEGER , where it should have been TYPES.BIGINT

Answer (score 0):

After Marmite Bomber pointed out that issue might be in the SQL. Made the below corrections
Before
 `public void saveRecordData(Long RecordId, RecordLog RecordLog) { Object[] parameters = {recordID, RecordLog.getRouteId(), RecordLog.getRecordType().getRecordTypeId(), RecordLog.getOrderId(), RecordLog.getIncomingRecordTimestamp(), RecordLog.getOutgoingRecordTimestamp(), RecordLog.getStatus()}; int[] types = {Types.INTEGER, Types.INTEGER, Types.INTEGER, Types.VARCHAR, Types.TIMESTAMP, Types.TIMESTAMP, Types.VARCHAR}; int rowsAffected = jdbcTemplate.update(INSERT_Record_LOG_SQL, parameters, types); }`

After ( changed the SQL Type from TYPES.INTEGER to TYPES.BIGINT )   `public void saveRecordData(Long RecordId, RecordLog RecordLog) { Object[] parameters = {recordID, RecordLog.getRouteId(), RecordLog.getRecordType().getRecordTypeId(), RecordLog.getOrderId(), RecordLog.getIncomingRecordTimestamp(), RecordLog.getOutgoingRecordTimestamp(), RecordLog.getStatus()}; int[] types = {Types.BIGINT, Types.INTEGER, Types.INTEGER, Types.VARCHAR, Types.TIMESTAMP, Types.TIMESTAMP, Types.VARCHAR}; int rowsAffected = jdbcTemplate.update(INSERT_Record_LOG_SQL, parameters, types); }`