# ERROR o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentImpl - Could not fetch the SequenceInformation from the database java.sql.SQLException: Numeric Overflow

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, entitymanager, hibernate-entitymanager

I'm trying to connect Oracle database using Entity Manager method.  Picking up oracle credentials from application.properties then the program is working fine I've referred this post [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58570032/hibernate-could-not-fetch-the-sequenceinformation-from-the-database/58574009#58574009][1], but its not applicable, since I need to use Entity Manager to set up username, password, url, etc. It seems like the Entity Manager didn't pick up oracle credentials. I am getting the following error:

```
    2021-07-14 14:15:56 INFO  c.e.f.s.s.SpringBootPracticeApplication - The following profiles are active: default
    2021-07-14 14:15:56 INFO  o.s.b.d.restart.ChangeableUrls - The Class-Path manifest attribute in
    2021-07-14 14:15:56 INFO  o.s.b.d.e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor - Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
    2021-07-14 14:15:56 INFO  o.s.b.d.e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor - For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
    2021-07-14 14:15:57 INFO  o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
    2021-07-14 14:15:57 INFO  o.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate - Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 44 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
    2021-07-14 14:15:58 INFO  o.s.b.w.e.tomcat.TomcatWebServer - Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
    2021-07-14 14:15:58 INFO  o.a.catalina.core.StandardService - Starting service [Tomcat]
    2021-07-14 14:15:58 INFO  o.a.catalina.core.StandardEngine - Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.45]
    2021-07-14 14:15:58 INFO  o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] - Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
    2021-07-14 14:15:58 INFO  o.s.b.w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1780 ms
    2021-07-14 14:15:58 INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Starting...
    2021-07-14 14:15:58 INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
    2021-07-14 14:15:58 INFO  o.s.b.a.h.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration - H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:mem:3d872e1e-07c6-4088-b9fa-19b41bd383f2'
  
    2021-07-14 14:15:58 INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-2 - Starting...
    2021-07-14 14:15:59 INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-2 - Start completed.
    2021-07-14 14:15:59 INFO  o.h.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper - HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
    2021-07-14 14:15:59 INFO  org.hibernate.Version - HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.30.Final
    2021-07-14 14:15:59 INFO  o.h.annotations.common.Version - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
    2021-07-14 14:15:59 INFO  org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
    2021-07-14 14:16:06 ERROR o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentImpl - Could not fetch the SequenceInformation from the database
    java.sql.SQLException: Numeric Overflow
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.NumberCommonAccessor.throwOverflow(NumberCommonAccessor.java:4139)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.NumberCommonAccessor.getLong(NumberCommonAccessor.java:636)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedStatement.getLong(GeneratedStatement.java:208)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedScrollableResultSet.getLong(GeneratedScrollableResultSet.java:261)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedResultSet.getLong(GeneratedResultSet.java:560)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.getLong(HikariProxyResultSet.java)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.resultSetMinValue(SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.java:134)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.extractMetadata(SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.java:60)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentImpl.sequenceInformationList(JdbcEnvironmentImpl.java:403)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentImpl.<init>(JdbcEnvironmentImpl.java:268)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:114)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
        at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
        at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
        at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:176)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:127)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1224)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1255)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1845)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1782)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:782)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:774)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1340)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1329)
        at com.sample.springbootpractice.src.SpringBootPracticeApplication.main(SpringBootPracticeApplication.java:18)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
2021-07-14 14:16:06 INFO  o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator - HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-07-14 14:16:07 INFO  o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-07-14 14:16:07 INFO  o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer - LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2021-07-14 14:16:07 WARN  o.s.b.a.o.j.JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration - spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2021-07-14 14:16:07 INFO  o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor - Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-07-14 14:16:07 INFO  o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver - Exposing 13 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2021-07-14 14:16:07 INFO  o.s.b.w.e.tomcat.TomcatWebServer - Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2021-07-14 14:16:07 INFO  c.e.f.s.s.SpringBootPracticeApplication - Started SpringBootPracticeApplication in 11.49 seconds (JVM running for 13.003)
2021-07-14 14:16:08 INFO  o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] - Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-07-14 14:16:08 INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-07-14 14:16:08 INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Completed initialization in 2 ms
```

It seems like it didn't pick up the dialect property. Here is my configuration file:

package com.sample.springbootpractice.src.configuration;

```
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig;
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnProperty;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Properties;


@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Profile("default")
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "source-system", havingValue = "ebs")
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "ebsEntityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "ebsTransactionManager",
        basePackages = {"com.sample.springbootpractice.src.user.repository.ebs"})
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class EbsDataSourceConfig {
    @Value("${source-system}")
    private String source;

    @Value("${aws-secret-name}")
    private String awsSecretName;

    private HashMap<String, String> getAwsSecretValues() {

        HashMap<String, String> awsSecretKeyValuesMap = new HashMap<>();
        System.out.println("Get values from AWS Secrets Manager for Secret : " + awsSecretName);
        awsSecretKeyValuesMap.put("ebs_jdbc_url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@...");
        awsSecretKeyValuesMap.put("ebs_write_username", "xxx");
        awsSecretKeyValuesMap.put("ebs_write_password", "xxx");
        return awsSecretKeyValuesMap;
    }

    private Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect",
                "com.sample.springbootpractice.src.configuration.CustomOracleDialect");
        return properties;
    }

    public DataSource getEbsOracleDataSource() {
        HashMap<String, String> awsSecretKeyValuesMap = getAwsSecretValues();
        String jdbcUrl, userName, userPasswd, driverClassName;

        jdbcUrl = awsSecretKeyValuesMap.get("ebs_jdbc_url");
        userName = awsSecretKeyValuesMap.get("ebs_write_username");
        userPasswd = awsSecretKeyValuesMap.get("ebs_write_password");
        driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver";
        System.out.println("Setting Oracle JPA");

        HikariConfig jdbcConfig = new HikariConfig();
        jdbcConfig.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
        jdbcConfig.setJdbcUrl(jdbcUrl);
        jdbcConfig.setUsername(userName);
        jdbcConfig.setPassword(userPasswd);
        /** Set the SQL string that will be executed on all new connections when they are created, before they are added to the pool. */
        jdbcConfig.setConnectionInitSql("SELECT 1 FROM dual");
        jdbcConfig.setConnectionTestQuery("SELECT 1 FROM dual");

        return new HikariDataSource(jdbcConfig);
    }

    @Bean(name = "ebsEntityManager")
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean oracleEntityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(getEbsOracleDataSource());
        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

        em.setPackagesToScan("com.sample.springbootpractice.src.user.entity.ebs");
        return em;
    }

    @Bean(name = "ebsTransactionManager")
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier("ebsEntityManager") EntityManagerFactory ebsEntityManager) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(ebsEntityManager);
        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

Here is my CustomOracleDialect file.

```
package com.sample.springbootpractice.src.configuration;


import org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect;
import org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.SequenceInformationExtractorOracleDatabaseImpl;
import org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.spi.SequenceInformationExtractor;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

class AppSequenceInformationExtractor extends SequenceInformationExtractorOracleDatabaseImpl {
    /**
     * Singleton access
     */
    public static final AppSequenceInformationExtractor INSTANCE = new AppSequenceInformationExtractor();

    @Override
    protected Long resultSetMinValue(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
        return resultSet.getBigDecimal("min_value").longValue();
    }
}

public class CustomOracleDialect extends Oracle12cDialect {

    @Override
    public SequenceInformationExtractor getSequenceInformationExtractor() {
        return AppSequenceInformationExtractor.INSTANCE;
    }

    @Override
    public String getQuerySequencesString() {
        return "select * from user_sequences";
    }
}
```

Here is my application.properties file

```
 # logging
    logging.pattern.console=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
    logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=info
    logging.level.root=INFO
    logging.level.org.springframework=info
    ## to enable all (*) actuator endpoints ##
    management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
    # Oracle settings
    spring.jpa.show-sql=false
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxx
    spring.datasource.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    spring.datasource.username=xxx
    spring.datasource.password=xxx
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=com.sample.springbootpractice.src.configuration.CustomOracleDialect
    # Issue with newer versions of Hibernate thus created custom Dialect
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=30
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates=true
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.batch_versioned_data=true
    spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true
    spring.datasource.hikari.validationTimeout=50000
    spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=30000
    spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=2
    spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=20
    spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=300000
    spring.datasource.hikari.max-lifetime=1200000
    spring.datasource.hikari.auto-commit=false
```

Answer (score 1):

You are configuring Hibernate directly in code so you don’t need the `spring.jpa.properties.` prefix.

Updated `additionalProperties()` method:

```
private Properties additionalProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect",
            "com.sample.springbootpractice.src.configuration.CustomOracleDialect");
    return properties;
}
```