# Numeric Overflow exception when calling findRevisions() or even custom audit query - spring-data-jpa with oracle

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, oracle11g, spring-data-envers

I'm struggling with exception since the past 4 days and being completely frustrated with it that I'm asking this question, I have referred various answers already on StackoverOverflow but they dont seem to have the issue as mine, so please don't mark it as duplicate.

[Hibernate could not fetch the SequenceInformation from the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58570032/hibernate-could-not-fetch-the-sequenceinformation-from-the-database)

I have spring data jpa 2.4.4 version and I'm using spring data envers with spring boot on oracle database, I have ojdbc 7 as a dependency.

All my tables are audited using envers and generated automatically by confirguration, so Im facing Numeric overflow exception when Im trying to fetch records whose rev is Number(10), my rev table has 2 columns where rev is a Number(10) digits precision.

REVINFO table is auto generated by spring data envers and i have not customised it in my code.

```
REVINFO table columns :
REV            NUMBER(10)
REVTIMESTAMP   TIMESTAMP
```

Main Table - Immigration_file

```
@Entity
@Audited
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ImmigrationFile extends BaseEntity implements ImmigrationFileAware<ImmigrationFile>,Serializable, Cloneable {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "IMMIGRATION_FILE_ID_GENERATOR",
            sequenceName = "SEQ_IMMIGRATION_FILE_ID",
            allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "IMMIGRATION_FILE_ID_GENERATOR")
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Long immigrationFileId;

...other columns
}
```

Audit table - Immigration_file_hist, having all columns of main table along with REV and REVTYPE, so the error is being thrown when the value of REV is "4686710314".

I have tried both the approached of using RevisionRepository and custom Audit Query and I get the same exception with both of them
code to fetch the revisions of immigration_file_hist repository

```
@Repository
public interface ImmigrationFileDaoRepository extends RevisionRepository<ImmigrationFile, Long, BigInteger>, JpaRepository<ImmigrationFile, Long> {

        Page<Revision<BigInteger, ImmigrationFile>> revisions = immigrationFileDaoRepository.findRevisions(immigrationFile.getImmigrationFileId(), PageRequest.of(Integer.valueOf(startPageIndex), Integer.valueOf(endPageIndex), RevisionSort.desc()));
```

I was using Long earlier and i have changed it to BigInteger and i still face the same issue.

Custom Audit Query

```
public List<ImmigrationFile> findRevisions(Long immigrationFileId) {
        AuditReader reader = AuditReaderFactory.get(entityManager);
        List<ImmigrationFile> results = reader
                .createQuery()
                .forRevisionsOfEntity(ImmigrationFile.class, true, false)
                .add(AuditEntity.id().eq(immigrationFileId))
                .addOrder(AuditEntity.property("version").desc())
                .setMaxResults(maxResult)
                .getResultList();
        return results;
```

Im getting the below exception :

```
 Caused by: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute query; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:331)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:548)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy252.findRevisions(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:687)
    ... 82 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2853)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2832)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2664)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2659)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:506)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:400)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1414)/
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1565)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1533)
    at org.hibernate.envers.query.internal.impl.AbstractAuditQuery.buildAndExecuteQuery(AbstractAuditQuery.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.envers.query.internal.impl.RevisionsOfEntityQuery.getQueryResults(RevisionsOfEntityQuery.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.envers.query.internal.impl.RevisionsOfEntityQuery.list(RevisionsOfEntityQuery.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.envers.query.internal.impl.AbstractAuditQuery.getResultList(AbstractAuditQuery.java:112)
    at org.springframework.data.envers.repository.support.EnversRevisionRepositoryImpl.findRevisions(EnversRevisionRepositoryImpl.java:155)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:524)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.Reposito.ryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:531)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:156)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:131)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:371)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:134)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
    ... 97 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Numeric Overflow
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.NumberCommonAccessor.throwOverflow(NumberCommonAccessor.java:4139)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.NumberCommonAccessor.getInt(NumberCommonAccessor.java:125)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedStatement.getInt(GeneratedStatement.java:199)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedScrollableResultSet.getInt(GeneratedScrollableResultSet.java:246)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedResultSet.getInt(GeneratedResultSet.java:556)
    at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcResultSet.getInt(WSJdbcResultSet.java:1089)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.IntegerTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(IntegerTypeDescriptor.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:329)
    at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.hydrate(ManyToOneType.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.hydrate(ComponentType.java:670)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:803)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:727)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowsFromResultSet(Loader.java:1039)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:990)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:959)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2850)
    ... 131 common frames omitted
```

Comment: What exactly is this type: `Number(10)`.  I'm not an expert in JPA but I don't see where this comes from.  I see `numeric(p,s)` in the SQL docs but nothing is `Number`.  Being more clear what this is would help here.

Comment: rev is the column autogenerated in revinfo table from spring data envers, which of type Number(10)

Comment: did you check in google what Number(10) data type represents in java? You might end up writing converter

Comment: at oracle.jdbc.driver.NumberCommonAccessor.throwOverflow(NumberCommonAccessor.java:4139)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.NumberCommonAccessor.getInt(NumberCommonAccessor.java:125)
Integer value is being picked up from Oracle by getInt method, Im not sure which class to extend so that I write the rs.getLong() or rs.getBigInteger().

Answer (score 1):

A revision number(`REV`) value should always be increasing and never overflows.

The default implementations provided by Envers use an `int` data type that has an upper bound of `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Since you have already mentioned that your `REV` number has the value of `4686710314` and it exceeds this limit, that's why you are getting a Numeric Overflow exception.

To resolve this issue, you can modify the data type of the `REV` column in the `REVINFO` table to accommodate larger values. But this is not possible in your case as the `REVINFO` is auto-generated.

So you should consider using a custom revision entity mapping using a `long` data type.

Below is the implementation

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "REV_INFO")
@RevisionEntity
public  class CustomRevisionEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8530213963961662300L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @RevisionNumber
    @Column(name = "REV")
    private long id;

    @RevisionTimestamp
    @Column(name = "REVTSTMP")
    private long timestamp;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Transient
    public Date getRevisionDate() {
        return new Date( timestamp );
    }

    public long getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(long timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }
}
```

And then `RevisionRepository<ImmigrationFile, Long, Long>`

Note: Verify the autogenerated `REVINFO` table `REV` column datatype length in Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `int` or `long` for identifiers and numbers retrieved from database. Most likely you do not perform any mathematical operations with them anyway.

Oracle stores numbers in decimal format, the corresponding type in Java is `BigDecimal`.

Your stack trace shows it:

```
at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedResultSet.getInt(GeneratedResultSet.java:556)
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcResultSet.getInt(WSJdbcResultSet.java:1089)
```

You're calling `getInt()` on ResultSet, you should call `getBigDecimal()`

Comment: Im not defining the audit class, is it auto generated using spring data envers which has the identifer (REV) which it is taking it as int when it should have been long.

Comment: Hibernate should map Oracle NUMBERs to Java BigDecimal by default. Try to switch the query to `findRevisions(BigDecimal immigrationFileId)`

Comment: I just tried with BigDecimal and it failed with the same exception :(